# Jikes RVM as distributed compiler

Tags: java, compiler-construction, distributed-computing, jikes

Can we use Jikes RVM as distributed compiler?

Thanks 
Rahul

Answer (score 0):

It seems very unlikely, unless I've misunderstood your question.

Jikes RVM is a virtual machine.  It operates on files that are already compiled.

As for the "distributed" part, I'm not sure that there is anything inherently distributed about its operation.

So in summary, I don't think so.